# Не могу создать директорию в Android

Tags: java, android

Почему не получается получить доступ к директории и создать там файл?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.testapp">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:minSdkVersion="20" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.testapp"
    tools:targetApi="31"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

В файле MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.testapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                MainActivity.createNote(MainActivity.this, "/Android/data/", "test.txt");
            }
        });
    }

    public static void createNote(Context context, String directory, String filename) {

        try {

            File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + directory);

            /**
            *   Возвращает java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array. Если создать в /Android/ свою папку (/Android/MyFolder), то всё работает, но...
            */
            for(File myDir : dir.listFiles()) {
                Log.d("Name", myDir.getName());
            }

            /**
            *   Теперь появляется ошибка java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted
            */
            File file = new File(dir, filename);
            file.createNewFile();


        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

У вас низачто не получиться создать файл в папке Android/data так как этот каталог защищён от записи

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я почему-то так и подумал, что дело в этом. Теперь буду знать наверняка.